# Remove of attribute of the hide elemnt to fix Styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have a page that has cards ,that get data from JSON ,what the problem is when i hide some element it leave white space and break the styling .how could i fix it i tried to delelte if the element has an attribute `display:none` it should `remove()`

here is some photos how it looks :
when i click on class1

[image: Image one]

class2 :

[image: image two]

my js :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(function () {
    $.getJSON("links.json", function (data) {
      $.each(data, function (key) {
        $(".mdc-list").append(
          "<a class='mdc-list-item' href='#'><span class='mdc-list-item__ripple'></span><span class='mdc-list-item__text'>" +
            key +
            "</span></a>"
        );
      });
      $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        var keys = key;
        $.each(data[key], function (key, value) {
          //data-key...
          $(".card").append(
            "<div class='mdc-card'><a class='mdc-list-item' href=" +
              value.link +
              " data-key=" +
              keys +
              "><span class=''></span><span><img class='mdc-img' src=" +
              value.link +
              "></span><span  class='mdc-list-item__text'>" +
              value.name +
              "</span></a></div> "
          );
          $(".mdc-card .mdc-list-item").hide();
        });
      });
      //});

      //on click of a tag
      $(document).on("click", ".mdc-list-item", function () {
        //get key
        var key = $(this).find(".mdc-list-item__text").text().trim();
        console.log(key);
        $(".main").hide();
        $(".mdc-card .mdc-list-item").hide();
        if ($(".mdc-card .mdc-list-item").hasOwnProperty("display:none")) {
          $(".mdc-card .mdc-list-item").remove();
        }
        $(".mdc-card .mdc-list-item[data-key=" + key + "]").show();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Html:

```
 <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
      .mdc-top-app-bar {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #009688;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .card {
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-grow: 5;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: space-around;
      }
      .mdc-card .mdc-list-item {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
      }
      .mdc-card {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-around;
        max-width: 260px;
        margin-top: 10px;
      }
      .mdc-img {
        width: 260px;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .main-photo {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        bottom: 0;
        margin-top: 200px;
      }
      .main {
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
      }
    </style>

    <title>Links</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="mdc-top-app-bar">
      <div class="mdc-top-app-bar__row">
        <section
          class="mdc-top-app-bar__section mdc-top-app-bar__section--align-start"
        >
          <button
            id="btn"
            class="material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__navigation-icon mdc-icon-button"
            aria-label="Open navigation menu"
          >
            menu
          </button>
          <span class="mdc-top-app-bar__title">Links</span>
        </section>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div>
      <section id="drawer">
        <aside class="mdc-drawer mdc-drawer--modal">
          <div class="mdc-drawer__content">
            <h3>Links</h3>
            <nav class="mdc-list"></nav>
          </div>
        </aside>
        <div id="scrollbar" class="mdc-drawer-scrim"></div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="main-photo">
      <img class="main" src="" alt="" />
    </div>
    <script>
      const topAppBarElement = document.querySelector(".mdc-top-app-bar");
      const topAppBar = mdc.topAppBar.MDCTopAppBar.attachTo(topAppBarElement);

      const drawer = mdc.drawer.MDCDrawer.attachTo(
        document.querySelector(".mdc-drawer")
      );
```

and here you can have a look on the page
my sandbox :
https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-sun-fo3si?file=/index.html

```
  topAppBar.setScrollTarget(document.getElementById("scrollbar"));
  topAppBar.listen("MDCTopAppBar:nav", () => {
    drawer.open = !drawer.open;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, but this code is not correct `$(".mdc-card .mdc-list-item").hasOwnProperty("display:none")` method `hasOwnProperty` check if object have field or method not to test if the jQuery object have style. To test if the object is hidden you need to use `!$(".mdc-card .mdc-list-item").is(':visible')`.

Comment: Also, you're selecting all items, not the one your click on, to get the item you just clicked you need to use `mdc_list_item = $(this);` inside click event, and inside `each` loop you need to save your item in variable to access it because you're hiding all items, not the one you just created.

Comment: i am trying as the photos one and two that when i add `hide()` it hide the element but it leave space the break my style and thanks for you comment @jcubic

Comment: how it is possible to do that could you help with?

Comment: I think that the issue is that you're not hiding `mdc-card` but `mdc-list-item` so they remain as flex items with 0 width. You're hiding link instead of div.

Comment: but when i hide `mdc-card ` it hide all cards

Comment: i did use it but it dosent shows any cards any more ,you could have look on my sandboxand you see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide `mdc-card` not the link inside because you will get flex items that have 0 widths and it will break the layout.

```js
$(".mdc-card").hide();
$(".mdc-card .mdc-list-item[data-key=" + key + "]").closest(".mdc-card").show();
```

And you need to update this:

```js
$(".card")
    .append(
      "<div class='mdc-card'><a class='mdc-list-item' href=" +
        value.link +
        " data-key=" +
        keys +
        "><span class=''></span><span><img class='mdc-img' src=" +
        value.link +
        "></span><span  class='mdc-list-item__text'>" +
        value.name +
        "</span></a></div> "
    )
    .find(".mdc-card")
    .hide();
```

or even better:

```js
var card_item = $("<div class='mdc-card'><a class='mdc-list-item' href=" +
        value.link +
        " data-key=" +
        keys +
        "><span class=''></span><span><img class='mdc-img' src=" +
        value.link +
        "></span><span  class='mdc-list-item__text'>" +
        value.name +
        "</span></a></div> ").hide();

$(".card").append(card_item);
```

NOTE:

```js
if ($(".mdc-card .mdc-list-item").hasOwnProperty("display:none")) {
      $(".mdc-card .mdc-list-item").remove();
}
```

this code makes no sense, it will always be false because jQuery object never has `display:none` property.

Comment: i did try this solution still not working all card disappear

Comment: @simao see my edit, I forget that you hide the link initialiy.